# Amadeus Self Service API making a post request

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, amadeus

I am trying to make a post request to Amadeus Self Service API but I am receiving the error below. I hope someone can help me.

`Uncaught (in promise) FetchError: [POST] "http://localhost:2801/flight-offers/upselling": <no response> Failed to fetch at async $fetch2 (ofetch.00501375.mjs?v=b3021059:261:15) at async submitBrandedOffers (upselling.vue:25:20)`

Server

```
app.post(`/flight-offers/upselling`, (req, res) => {
  const flight = req.body.flight;
  amadeus.shopping.flightOffers.upselling
    .post(
      JSON.stringify({
        data: {
          type: 'flight-offers-upselling',
          flightOffers: [flight],
        },
      })
    )
    .then(function (response) {
      res.send(response.result);
    })
    .catch(function (response) {
      res.send(response);
    });
});
```

Template

```
const offer = route.query.offer_id;
async function submitBrandedOffers() {
  const response = await $fetch(
    'http://localhost:2801/flight-offers/upselling',
    {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'cors',
      cache: 'no-cache',
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      redirect: 'follow',
      referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer',
      body: JSON.stringify(offer), 
    }
  );
  // console.log(response.json());
  return await response.json();
}
submitBrandedOffers();
```

I am unable to get a response and I think I am not accessing the server.

Comment: I take it your server is sending CORS headers in the response? but I guess you'd see CORS errors in the browser if that were the issue, and you didn't mention any - it looks like the server at `localhost:2801` isn't working at all. Is the server running at all?

Comment: Yes, the server is working. I can send get request. I even use the same headers i used in get request with additional of body. I think I am not hitting the endpoint as in the analytics the branded upselling is not incrementing.

Comment: `in the analytics the branded upselling is not incrementing` is that what `amadeus.shopping.flightOffers.upselling` is supposed to do? are you sending `flight` in the body? i.e. what is the value of `req.body.flight`

Comment: If i add ()=> bofore the endpoint, I am now seeing 'http://localhost:2801/flight-offers/upselling'": 404 Page not found:

Comment: what does `If i add ()=> bofore the endpoint` even mean? try `console.log(flight)` after `const flight = req.body.flight;` - I suspect your issue is lack of body parsers in your server code

Comment: Yes it should increment. I tried to make a post request in postman and it increment. The value of the flight is the flight offer. {
  "type": "flight-offer",
  "id": "1",
  "source": "GDS",

Comment: Even if I dont have a body, it should still connect to the server and it will give me error.

Comment: unless `const flight = req.body.flight;` throws an error, of course

Comment: flight returns the flight-offer.

Comment: @JaromandaX I checked my server and you were right, I dont have body parser. I installed body parser but still receiving error. I am new to this, If you have time could you please take a look at my server and template code? Thanks. https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-surf-qckrkq?file=/server/index.js

Comment: in the code you posted here, you have `const flight = req.body.flight;` - on the codesandbox you have `flightOfffer = req.body;` - you haven't even declared the variable (which could throw an error) and it's completely different to what you're doing here ... so ... you're doing *something wrong™* - but I can't tell you where

Comment: Sorry for the confusion because I tried to fix it and made different versions of it. In my server i get SyntaxError: Unexpected token " in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: then some JSON you think you're getting isn't JSON

Comment: I got some progress, i added strict: false in app.use(bodyParser.json({ strict: false })); and now I can hit the endpoint and i can console log the flight sent from the body. but it crashes saying Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client